# Simulation / Emulation of an I2C EEPROM MEMORY (M24LC16B)

Tags: i2c, simulation, eeprom

I'm using iBurner3.2 I2C Bus EEPROM Programmer to write and read from an I2C EEPROM MEMORY (24LC16B) using COM Port, I want to simulate the behavior of this specific I2C EEPROM, is there any software tool that can simulate/emulate its behavior. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try Proteus in evaluation period. It's not good as a whole, but should be enough to simulate 1 EEPROM, also it can be connected to a com port with a serial virtual port software.

Answer (score 0):

For an I2C eeprom you can manage with a micro controller acting as an I2C slave, just you need to process any messages quickly, as you do not control the clock, and most devices do not support slave clock stretching,

on top of this you will also need to handle what communication method your using to talk to the micro, remebering that this cannot interrupt the I2C handling,

Other methods for on the fly modification of content is either FPGA to use internal memory, or 2 EEPROMS with the clock and data lines switched, so you can program 1 while the other is in use, then when the clock is idle for long enough you switch back over to the new programmed one.